# Not getting suggestion in between the text

Tags: jquery

When I continuously type , I get auto suggestions but when I try to enter the text in between the text then I didnot get an suggestion
Any suggestion please..
here is the code:

(Type `the is` and try to add text between `the` and `is`)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function AutoSuggestControl(id_or_element /*:HTMLInputElement*/) {
    this.provider /*:SuggestionProvider*/ = new wordSuggestions();
    this.textbox /*:HTMLInputElement*/ = typeof id_or_element == "string" ? document.getElementById(id_or_element) : id_or_element;
    this.init();

}


AutoSuggestControl.prototype.autosuggest = function (aSuggestions /*:Array*/) {

    //make sure there's at least one suggestion

    if (aSuggestions.length > 0) {
        this.typeAhead(aSuggestions[0]);
    }
};

AutoSuggestControl.prototype.handleKeyUp = function (oEvent /*:Event*/) {

    var iKeyCode = oEvent.keyCode;
    var evtobj = oEvent;
    window.eventobj = evtobj;
    if ((iKeyCode != 16 && iKeyCode < 32) || (iKeyCode >= 33 && iKeyCode <= 46) || (iKeyCode >= 112 && iKeyCode <= 123) || (iKeyCode == 65 && evtobj.ctrlKey) || (iKeyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey)) {
        //ignore
        if (iKeyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
            // window.getSelection().deleteFromDocument();
            // TODO: need to find a way to select the rest of the text and delete.
        }
    } else {
        //request suggestions from the suggestion provider
        this.provider.requestSuggestions(this)
    }
};


AutoSuggestControl.prototype.init = function () {

    //save a reference to this object
    var oThis = this;
    //assign the onkeyup event handler
    lastDate = new Date();
    oThis.textbox.onkeyup = function (oEvent) {

        //check for the proper location of the event object
        if (!oEvent) {
            oEvent = window.event;
        }
        newDate = new Date();
        if (newDate.getTime() > lastDate.getTime() + 200) {
            oThis.handleKeyUp(oEvent);
            lastDate = newDate;
        }
    };

};

AutoSuggestControl.prototype.selectRange = function (iStart /*:int*/, iLength /*:int*/) {
    //use text ranges for Internet Explorer
    if (this.textbox.createTextRange) {
        var oRange = this.textbox.createTextRange();
        oRange.moveStart("character", iStart);
        oRange.moveEnd("character", iLength);
        oRange.select();
        //use setSelectionRange() for Mozilla
    } else if (this.textbox.setSelectionRange) {
        this.textbox.setSelectionRange(iStart, iLength);
    }
    //set focus back to the textbox
    $('#textbox').focus().val($('#textbox').val());
    // this.textbox.focus();
};


AutoSuggestControl.prototype.typeAhead = function (sSuggestion /*:String*/) {

    //check for support of typeahead functionality
    if (this.textbox.createTextRange || this.textbox.setSelectionRange) {
        var lastSpace = this.textbox.value.lastIndexOf(" ");
        var lastQuote = this.textbox.value.lastIndexOf("'");
        var lastHypen = this.textbox.value.lastIndexOf("-");
        var lastDoubleQuote = this.textbox.value.lastIndexOf('"');
        var lastEnter = this.textbox.value.lastIndexOf("\n");
        var lastIndex = Math.max(lastSpace, lastEnter, lastQuote, lastHypen, lastDoubleQuote) + 1;
        var contentStripped = this.textbox.value.substring(0, lastIndex);
        var lastWord = this.textbox.value.substring(lastIndex, this.textbox.value.length);
        this.textbox.value = contentStripped + sSuggestion; //.replace(lastWord,"");
        var start = this.textbox.value.length - sSuggestion.replace(lastWord, "").length;
        var end = this.textbox.value.length;
        this.selectRange(start, end);
    }
};


wordSuggestions.prototype.requestSuggestions = function (oAutoSuggestControl /*:AutoSuggestControl*/) {
    var aSuggestions = [];
    var sTextbox = oAutoSuggestControl.textbox.value;
    var sTextboxSplit = sTextbox.split(/[\s,]+/);
    var sTextboxLast = sTextboxSplit[sTextboxSplit.length - 1];
    var sTextboxValue = sTextboxLast;
    if (sTextboxValue.length > 0) {
        //search for matching words
        for (var i = 0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
            if (this.words[i].indexOf(sTextboxValue.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                if (this.words[i].indexOf(sTextboxValue) == 0) {
                    aSuggestions.push(this.words[i]);
                }
                else if (this.words[i].indexOf(sTextboxValue.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + sTextboxValue.slice(1)) == 0) {
                    aSuggestions.push(this.words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.words[i].slice(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    debugger;
    //provide suggestions to the control
    oAutoSuggestControl.autosuggest(aSuggestions);
};

function wordSuggestions() {
    this.words = ['the', 'and', 'that', 'for', 'with', 'yo', 'are', 'your', 'from', 'have', 'more', 'but', 'new', 'not', 'will', 'what', 'about', 'all', 'one', 'they', 'get', 'like', 'out', 'their', 'who', 'people', 'been', 'can', 'how', 'there', 'which', 'were', 'apple', 'time', 'when', 'just', 'into', 'said', 'our', 'here', 'also', 'year', 'view', 'these', 'comment', 'had', 'would', 'other', 'now', 'than', 'she', 'see', 'after', 'most', 'some', 'make', 'points', 'her', 'mobile', 'day', 'insider', 'point', 'company', 'over', 'twitter', 'use', 'right', 'say', 'could', 'them', 'way', 'first', 'why', 'ago', 'world', 'thing', 'only', 'login', 'even', 'before', 'because', 'any', 'two', 'million', 'please', 'device', 'service', 'phone', 'made', 'topic', 'while', 'best', 'work', 'last', 'know', 'network', 'read', 'him', 'much', 'want', 'those', 'where', 'follow', 'user', 'friend', 'may', 'then', 'going', 'still', 'well', 'look', 'being', 'post', 'think', 'photo', 'hour', 'many', 'take', 'image', 'back', 'got', 'video', 'should', 'off', 'very', 'site', 'come', 'good', 'recently', 'need', 'down', 'did', 'show', 'email', 'open', 'around', 'really', 'week', 'policy', 'using', 'through', 'big', 'today', 'game', 'alert', 'article', 'stock', 'too', 'media', 'next', 'product', 'find', 'android', 'own', 'during', 'free', 'market', 'story', 'lot', 'reading', 'term', 'social', 'feel', 'technology', 'share', 'every', 'able', 'shared', 'since', 'question', 'life', 'state', 'inc', 'home', 'few', 'told', 'never', 'president', 'data', 'something', 'job', 'house', 'report', 'used', 'better', 'another', 'window', 'city', 'according', 'content', 'system', 'via', 'part', 'government', 'same', 'help', 'man', 'let', 'both', 'disrupt', 'privacy', 'top', 'software', 'tech', 'number', 'percent', 'long', 'each', 'such', 'inside', 'car', 'line', 'month', 'three', 'actually', 'doe', 'live', 'end', 'money', 'might', 'billion', 'without', 'experience', 'little', 'found', 'future', 'great', 'school', 'put', 'information', 'between', 'already', 'must', 'case', 'quote', 'feature', 'though', 'ever', 'page', 'plan', 'including', 'tags', 'call', 'called', 'making', 'police', 'copyright', 'web', 'mean', 'change', 'password', 'seem', 'white', 'serving', 'powered', 'ask', 'reserved', 'idea', 'logged', 'tell', 'against', 'problem', 'give', 'working', 'learn', 'full', 'startup', 'continue', 'doing', 'team', 'acceptance', 'constitute', 'forgot', 'national', 'set', 'tablet', 'run', 'consumer', 'fact', 'yet', 'love', 'different', 'name', 'far', 'cant', 'women', 'registration', 'place', 'least', 'disclaimer', 'sale', 'directly', 'become', 'getting', 'real', 'update', 'party', 'play', 'advertising', 'writer', 'high', 'group', 'turn', 'keep', 'public', 'enough', 'ready', 'second', 'republican', 'health', 'everyone', 'once', 'away', 'pay', 'under', 'years', 'browser', 'five', 'past', 'buy', 'deal', 'old', 'left', 'store', 'former', 'small', 'early', 'computer', 'law', 'based', 'guy', 'looking', 'bad', 'office', 'covered', 'price', 'design', 'kind', 'bit', 'support', 'offer', 'search', 'note', 'person', 'start', 'likely', 'advertise', 'reason', 'guest', 'having', 'sure', 'took', 'hardware', 'per', 'screen', 'bill', 'respect', 'blog', 'space', 'taking', 'probably', 'platform', 'war', 'key', 'john', 'power', 'again', 'someone', 'seen', 'later', 'men', 'watch', 'family', 'hand', 'important', 'website', 'employee', 'version', 'however', 'care', 'believe', 'pretty', 'marketing', 'went', 'issue', 'official', 'trying', 'until', 'started', 'night', 'course', 'china', 'alway', 'intelligence', 'add', 'guideline', 'customer', 'instead', 'everything', 'security', 'current', 'building', 'asked', 'sign', 'anonymity', 'brand', 'hard', 'whether', 'country', 'coming', 'digital', 'revenue', 'manually', 'mac', 'scoop', 'amazon', 'wont', 'examples', 'gun', 'strong', 'four', 'hit', 'include', 'thought', 'latest', 'submitting', 'review', 'huge', 'launch', 'order', 'student', 'available', 'following', 'word', 'markup', 'coded', 'pro', 'especially', 'death', 'done', 'children', 'style', 'maybe', 'daily', 'credit', 'camera', 'talk', 'kid', 'control', 'below', 'among', 'came', 'example', 'event', 'blackberry', 'street', 'cost', 'fire', 'woman', 'picture', 'yahoo', 'industry', 'model', 'developer', 'black', 'running', 'source', 'anything', 'together', 'simply', 'major', 'this', 'commerce', 'book', 'allow', 'quarter', 'growth', 'behind', 'biggest', 'member', 'pap', 'business', 'chart', 'move', 'provide', 'court', 'face', 'almost', 'tax', 'stop', 'music', 'create', 'given', 'several', 'recent', 'university', 'project', 'map', 'display', 'lead', 'head', 'try', 'air', 'popular', 'thank', 'young', 'result', 'known', 'gay', 'program', 'account', 'side', 'invest', 'cut', 'star', 'wanted', 'release', 'images', 'possible', 'list', 'act', 'college', 'anyone', 'history', 'often', 'earlier', 'link', 'focused', 'sheet', 'saw', 'shot', 'clear', 'either', 'worked', 'message', 'area', 'dead', 'center'];
}
       $(document).ready(function(){
                  var oTextbox = new AutoSuggestControl("textbox");
                  });
```

Comment: sorry, couldn't get you....

Comment: I couldnot add jsfiddle in my question..sorry for that.here is the jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/x9a9q7jp/ @BhojendraNepal

Comment: You could have added the code in the question itself

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937569/jquery-autocomplete-for-text-area) will help you

Comment: No that is not what I want..plz read my updated question @BhojendraNepal