# multi line input / textarea while filling it using the browsers autocomplete

Tags: html, cross-browser

I need to create a resizable textarea / input.
That's the easy part if I'm using a textarea.

The issue that I'm facing is that one of resizable inputs should be an email field and we want that the browser will autocomplete this field using emails that the user entered in other sites.

As far as I know, that's not doable but I'm taking a shot here and hope to find a solution here.

I'll appreciate your help.

Nadav

Comment: Perhaps this thread would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937569/jquery-autocomplete-for-text-area

Comment: The autocomplete parameter for html5 has been discussed in another question.
 
<input autocomplete="on">


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568609/autocomplete-text-input-for-html5

Comment: @JustinMcKee - thanks, but I'm talking about textarea - not input.